# Change the Sender in Outlook using Redemption, but not with an account in the profile

Tags: outlook-redemption

I'm attempting to create Outlook emails that should be sent "from" someone other than the person actually sending the email. The idea is to prefill the email, display it in Outlook, allowing the end user to modify before sending. As a part of that process, I would like to use a different email address, which is a true email address, but is not an account in the end user's profile.

If this were SMTP, I could use the Net.Mail classes, which will accept any smtp address as the sender. Like this:

string from = "mytest@myorg.com";
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(from, to);

My question then, is it possible to do this using Redemption? All the examples that I've been able to find talk about either accessing the "Sender" property, or the "SendUsingAccount" property. From what I can tell, these both require an Account in the user profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sending using Exchange (as well as most SMTP servers), it will not let you spoof the sender. The user must actually have the right to send as that user.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. When you say "have the right" does that mean it must be an account in the user's profile, or can the permission be applied to, say, a public folder?

Comment: Neither - an Exchange admin can give a user the right to send on behalf of another user.